# Representing a surface in $z = f(x,y)$ form near a point.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

here is the question:

Can the surface whose equation is $xy-y \log (z)+\sin (xz)=0$ be represented in form $z=f(x,y)$ near $(0,2,1)$

If $z$ is going to be one, wouldn't that automatically make it $f(x,y)$ ? Can it really be that simple?

thanks for hints/help guys.

Comment: It says _near_ $(0,2,1)$, so $z$ will be close to $1$ but not necessarily equal to $1$. Have you learned the implicit function theorem?

Comment: maybe a long time ago. thanks for the heads up I will look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I think I have a solution, could someone check it ?

$F\left(x,y,z\right) = xy-y\log \left(z\right)+\sin \left(xz\right)$

$F_z = x\cos \left(xz\right) - \frac{y}{z} \Rightarrow\left(0,2,1\right) = -2 \not =0$ Therefore by IFT there is a form $z=f\left(x,y\right)$ near point $\left(0,2,1\right)$